# Copy features with their related tables

Tags: file-geodatabase, feature-class, relates, copy, loading

I have two file geodatabases with identical schema that have a feature class and four related tables. I need to copy features from one to the other with the information from all of the related tables.

Does anyone have a work flow for this?

All of the standard ways of moving data (append, simple data loader, copy) do not accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Copy or append? Is target database empty?

Comment: Copy or append, it doesn't matter. I need to move features and their rows in the related tables to another geo-database that is already populated with data.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What precisely have you tried?

Comment: you need to use append, and you will have to do it 5 times for the featureclass and each related flattable.  If they match exact you can run it in TEST mode, if they are slightly different you can use NO_TEST.

Comment: Why would you put this question on hold? it is a perfectly reasonable question to ask here. The traditional methods of moving features from one feature class to another, append, data loader, copy, do not accomplish my stated goal of moving the features and the information stored in a related table.

Comment: @ed.hank If I use append for the feature class and each table how would it maintain the relationship when the global and real ID change?

Comment: Ahh yeah I didnt realize you were using the globalID or ObjectID as the primary key.   That is a problem,  I dont have a solution for that off the top of my head.

Comment: Search "append with attachments" on Google. I think script needs a bit of modification to solve your issue. Works perfectly fine for same schemas feature classes.

Comment: @ajc5286 - i voted to reopen this.  this is a very good question and something I would like to know the answer to as well.  any chance you tried that script felixip mentioned?

Comment: @ed.hank I went with a hybrid of your idea. I did an append for the feature class and each of the related tables then wrote a script with an update cusor to look through another common filed from both the feature class and and the tables, and update the related global ID.